# Can you draw a diagonal rectangle with drawRect?

Tags: java, applet, awt, java-2d

I've been trying to draw a simple figure, however I'm having issues drawing arms. Whenever I use drawRect it just draws a horizontal or a straight rectangle.

I've only tried drawRect since drawLine is not thick enough.

I'm expecting a diagonal rect or maybe a thicker line that could potentially look like an arm.

Comment: Kind of - the trick would be to rotate the rectangle

Comment: How do u do that?

Comment: `Graphics#rotate` might be the place you need to start. A more advanced approach would be to use `AffineTransform`, [for more details](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html)

Comment: i'll look it up, thanks

Comment: "*not thick enough*" => [Graphics2D::setStroke](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setStroke(java.awt.Stroke)) and [BasicStroke](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/BasicStroke.html)

Comment: So, there's no way of implementing this without Graphics2D?

Comment: you can set the pixels directly in an `BufferedImage`, but why not use the `Gaphics2D`? (usually the `Graphics` that you get is an instance of `Graphics2D`, it just needs a cast)

Comment: Thank u , I'm implementing it right now.